# consuming values from json file from private git repo using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab

I need to know how to consume a json file from a private gitlab repo using spring. I'm trying to access the json file from a private git repository using spring boot but unable to find it.

Comment: This question needs much more details. Maybe include some code, error messages...?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.